# Why cant't I combine document.getElementsByTagName and .addEventListener in this case?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, addeventlistener, getelementsbytagname

I am making a little *power point*, but I am stuck. When one `<input>` is clicked, I want to change a variable. I tried this :

HTML :

```
<input size="40">
<input size="40">
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
inputClicked = false;
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").addEventListener("click", function() {
  inputClicked = true;
});
```

```js
var inputClicked = false;
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").addEventListener("click", function() {
       inputClicked = true;
       alert(inputClicked);
});
```

```html
<input>
<input>
```

I you run this hided snippet, you will see, when the `<input>`s are clicked, no alert pops up. plz show me my error, or another way to do it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good thing about using `focus` instead of `click` is that you can use the tab key.

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
  console.log(event.target)
}, false)
```

If you have more than one input tag to handle:

```
const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))

inputs.forEach(function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('focus', function (event) {
    console.log(event)
  }, false)
})
```

Explanation:
`document.querySelectorAll('input')` returns a NodeList which is not an array. Array.from() converts the NodeList into an array.

Comment: Yes. You can look at the documentation on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

because by tag name you get an array of elements, you will need to iterate through that array and add event on every element. if you use jquery then it is possible to assign event on many elements at once.

you can do it like this:

**javascript**:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
for (i = 0;i<elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    inputClicked = true; 
  });
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("input").click(function(){
   inputClicked = true;
});
```